# Google Cloud Storage uploads with OkHttp - streaming vs multipart

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp to upload files to Google Cloud Storage. Right now, I'm doing a single PUT request with a custom request body and stream the data. The request is something like this:

```
 final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(uploadUrl)
                    .put(requestBody)
                    .addHeader("Content-Length", length)
                    .addHeader("Content-Range", range)
                    .build();
```

My `requestBody` handles reading of the file and writing to the `BufferedSink`, similar to the recipe for Post Streaming available here (https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes):

Will it be faster to move to uploading Multiple Chunks (as described here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload#upload-resumable - I *think* it should be achievable with OkHttp `MultipartBody.Builder`), or should I stick with streaming?